# Refraction / Reflection inside a sphere

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I would like to know how rays would be reflected when their focal point is exactly the center of a sphere.
I couldn't find this ideal though simple(?) concept but this here (Fig. 2) looks like the idea without the result(?):

[image: img]

My main question is actually: Will it be the same path just reverse?

Comment: If you fancy a more visual approach you can try running some ray tracing simulations, there is an example here of tracing a sphere https://github.com/danieljfarrell/pvtrace

Comment: As VinoRue's answer shows, the focus won't be there; you can still trace thru a sphere and see what kind of mess is on the output side - either refracted or reflected back into the sphere.

Comment: Do you mean a spherical mirror, where there is a focus exactly at the center of the spherical mirror? In that case, the new light just reflects exactly back, because the focal distance of a spherical mirror is $f=r/2$, and you have a focus exactly at $2f$. All rays will be radii, hence hitting the inside of the sphere at a normal angle, and so a perfect back reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The focal point could never be at the center of the sphere.

Actually, it is impossible for any ray entering a sphere to pass through the center unless the ray is initially directed towards the center (the middle ray in figure 2).

But why is this?

The radius of the sphere represents the normal of the surface of refraction. Consider a rectilinear surface, in what cases does the refracted ray propagate along the normal? The answer is that only when ray is initially directed along the normal.

Comment: Well said.  Now we need a **volunteer**   :-)  to solve for a thick biconvex lens such that the focal point is at the center of the lens  -- in which case symmetry clearly demonstrates that the exiting light rays will mimic the entering rays exactly.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Rays that are parallel with an ellipsoid's axis will focus the rays in to a point. So if a sphere, whose center is that focal point, is carved out of the ellipsoid then the resulting convex/concave lens will act as a perfect focusing device. A generalization from focusing paralell rays with an ellipsoid is the Caresian oval (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_oval ) that can project homocentric rays (ie. rays from one focus) into another other.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and well explained answer (btw, congrats for your first or one of your first contributions!). How would a ray be reflected when it is directed along the normal? Will it be the same path on its return?

Comment: @Ben 
/* How would a ray be reflected when it is directed along the normal? Will it be the same path on its return? */
Yes.